# Sequelize how to update records in foreign tables

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js, put

I have a these 3 tables:

Hotel
Filters
HotelFilters

I can add hotels, filters and the associated HotelFilters correctly like this:

```
// Create and Save a new Hotel
exports.create = async (req, res) => {

    // Create a Hotel
    const hotel = {
        title: req.body.title,
        ...
    };

    // This is an array of integers - assume we have 1,2,3,4 for now
    const filters = req.body.filters;

    await Hotel.create(hotel)
        .then(createdHotel => {
            // THIS ADDS RECORDS IN TABLE HOTELFILTERS*************************
            filters.forEach((filter) => {
                createdHotel.createHotelFilter({ filterId: filter });
            });

            res.send(createdHotel);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message:
                    err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Hotel."
            });
        });
};
```

The above works fine but pay attention to the comment (// THIS ADDS RECORDS IN TABLE HOTELFILTERS*************************). Now the issue is when I want to update the table:

If I remove the filters and send the data as below, I want to remove the hotel filter 4 that were added:

```
{
    "title": "Hotel",
    "description": "This is a description",
    "hotelFilters": [1,2,3 ]
}
```

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure this is the right answer because you didnt write it properly
But I hope this helps you :

```
await HotelFilter.destroy({
    where: {
        filterId: {
            [Op.notIn]: filters
        }
    }
});
```